# Exporting boost::asio::ip::address operator == to python

Tags: c++, python-2.7, boost-python

I'm trying to export boost::asio::ip::address to python using boost python.
Most of the class export is rather trivial for my needs as these are simple member functions.

However, when I come to export the comparison operators I see that they are defined like this:

```
friend bool operator==(const address& a1, const address& a2)
```

This syntax AFAIK declares the operator as a non member function, but rather a namespace function. (making it unexportable to python)

Is there a way I can tweak boost-python to export this to **cmp** operator to allow python to compare these objects for me? Or is my only option to write some wrapper to this class in C++ and implement proper member comparison functions there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, boost::python makes it quite easy. You can actually export any function as a class member if it takes a reference to the class as its first parameter. Here's a simple example:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using boost::python;

struct Test
{
    int i;
};

bool operator==(const Test& t1, const Test& t2)
{
    return t1.i == t2.i;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test)
{
    class_<Test>("Test")
        .def_readwrite("i", &Test::i)
        .def(self == self);
}
```

Voila! That's all you need.